# Convert JSON file to numpy array

Tags: python, json, numpy

This .json file contains record from ECG machine.
The file format looks like this:

```
[-0.140625,-0.15234375,-0.15234375,...,-0.19335937499999997,0 ]
```

However, when I try to use this code, it shows an error

```
def load_tester(path):
  dataset = '{"fruits": }'
  data = json.loads(path)
  print(data)
  return(np.asarray(nt))
```

this is the error:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I want to save that file into numpy array and become as same as the format that the json uses.

Comment: I do not think an `ndarray` can be saved into a json file, as it is. You could convert it to a `list` using `my_array.tolist()` and then store it to json.

Answer (score 11):

You are trying to load json usign a file name, but not data that is in the file

```
def load_tester(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    print(data)
    return np.asarray(data)
```

Comment: it can be either `json.load(f)` or `json.loads(f.read())`. Load accepts file like object, loads accepts str or bytes

Comment: tried it , it shows:
     TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Can you show how do you run it, please? The question mentions a json file (I assumed path is a file path to this file) with content being a list of floats. I tested it with `load_tester('x.json')` where `x.json` is a local file

Comment: "import json
    with open("package.json") as f:
          json.loads(f)"

Comment: Please read my comment about load/loads again. Just use load in your code and you will be fine. Atm you're trying to loads (that expects a string) but giving a file object as input

Comment: I need to save the file as .npy file after the conversion